# How do you fix an incompatible types error?

Tags: java, arrays

The program I wrote is giving me an error and i don't know how to fix it.

I've tried a few different things and they didn't work.

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);   
    return c == "a" || c == "e" || c == "i" || c == "o" || c == "u";
}
```

I want my program to run properly, the goal is for the code to return whether or not a string is a vowel.

Comment: `return "aeiou".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(c)) != -1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be comparing a character against *character* literals, not string literals:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```

You could try to streamline the above code by instead using a set to hold all possible acceptable input values:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
    return chars.contains(Character.toLowerCase(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you say `c == "a"`, you are essentially trying to compare your parameter, a character, with a string "a", and so on.

Try changing those lines to `c == 'a'` (single quotes to denote a character) and so on for the rest of your conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a `char`, `"a"` is a `String`. `char` and `String` are incompatible types.

`return c == "a" || c == "e" || c == "i" || c == "o" || c == "u";`

`c == "a"` You compare `char` and `String` values.

To fix this, I would change the line to

`return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';` to compare `c` to chars.